# How to move yanked text into particular register in vim?

Tags: vim

When editing in vim, often enough I find myself stopping when I'm going to delete text and I notice that previously yanked text would become handy for next operations.

So - how to move already yanked text into particular register (e.g. under <kbd>a</kbd>)?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question but are you aware of YankRing (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234)? It may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
noremap <leader>ma :let @a=@<CR>
```

Now, when you press `\ma` in normal mode, your last yanked text will go to register 'a'.
Note : Assuming leader is '\'

Comment: Is `m` mapped to something by default?

Answer (score 7):

To move register `0` to register `a`:

```
:let @a=@0
```

Comment: `:let @a=@"` works for me. Any ideas (mappings?) how to make it more handy? A bit too lazy to write command everytime. Takes less to paste and delete once more with specified register.

Comment: @Arnis bind it to a key? something like `:map <F3> :let @a=@"<CR>`

Comment: After the first time, you can just hit `:l` and then the up arrow to recall that command.  Well, assuming that you haven't run a different command that starts with `l` since that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `0` register, if you only need it for a short amount of time. From `:help quote_number` (just below `:help registers`):

> ```
> 2. Numbered registers "0 to "9         
>
> Vim fills these registers with text from yank and delete commands.
>    Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command, 
> unless the command specified another register with ["x].
> ```
>
> [(link to the rest)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can delete text to the devnull registry with `"_d` (actually it is called the blackhole registry). See `:help quote_`. No need then to move registers, your previously yanked text will still be available with `p`.

Comment: is it possible to map _d to dD? I think that would be most handy way to fix this problem. just holding shift when I don't want to lose previously yanked text...